# Changing relative heights of objects so that their shadows reflect what the user wants

Tags: inkscape, shadows, drop-shadow

How can I change this image so that the inner circles appear like they are at the highest level? Meaning that the outer and bigger circle doesn't cast a shadow over them?

[image]

Edit1: I am using Inkscape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclear in your question what app you're using, so I screencapped both Adobe Illustrator and Affinity Designer to show this applies to both for certain, and I'm pretty sure Inkscape and Xara and Sketch as well; It's all down to the ***draw order*** - which in Adobe Illustrator and Affinity Designer shows up clearly in the ***Layers*** palette.

If you select your smaller circles, and `right click` on them, you should get a context menu which says things like "Arrange> Bring/Move Forward", "Arrange> Bring/Move to Front", "Arrange> Bring/Move Backwards" and "Arrange> Bring/Move to Back" - these commands are how you control draw order on an individual graphic element (or multiple selected elements) outside of using the layers palette - you ***can*** also grab things *in* the ***Layers*** palette and ***drag*** them into a more correct order.

If your little circles are higher in the draw order - hence "above" your other elements, their drop shadows will be cast onto the lower elements as you desire.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can confirm Inkscape has the ability to shift Layer stacking in the **Layers** palette; not drag n drop, but using the arrows next to the layer name.

Comment: I am using Inkscape

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. I had a problem because my inner circles didn't have 100% opacity, so I was still seeing the shadow of the big circle on the little ones, but that has been solved.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly this all is already in G.Falla's answer, so upvote it if you see this useful

Draw the shadows as separate black low opacity blurred objects, do not use effects. You can place the shadows freely in the objects stack:

[image]

Comment: I like this solution. It will take a little more work but I see how easily I could make it work. Thank you!